Vertical alignment of equations in column environment
I'm trying to put two equations side by side in Beamer, both of them inside an \item in an \itemize environment. The code I'm using is:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[t, onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Gravitatorio o Coulombiano:
                \begin{equation*}
                    \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{x}) \sim \frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|^3}.
                \end{equation*}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Euler (2D):
                \begin{equation*}
                    \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{x}) \sim -\frac{\mathbf{x}^{\perp}}{|\mathbf{x}|^2}.
                \end{equation*}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


But the output is:

As you can see, the equations are not aligned vertically. How can I properly align them? Any help appreciated.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm sorry, I'm editing the question right away.

Issue a \strut with each of the \items to ensure they take up the same vertical space, and then use a \vphantom for the larger term in the right-hand equation.

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t, onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Gravitatorio o Coulombiano\strut:
          \[ \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{x}) \sim \frac{\mathbf{x}\vphantom{\mathbf{x}^\perp}}{\lvert \mathbf{x} \rvert^3}. \]
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Euler (2D)\strut:
          \[ \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{x}) \sim -\frac{\mathbf{x}^{\perp}}{\lvert \mathbf{x} \rvert^2}. \]
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


This is what I wanted, thank you so much!
